# VBA - How do I find the name of a shape created from an effect?

Tags: vba, draw

I was wondering if there is a more specific way to rename my shape extracted from a contour effect than using ActiveLayer.Shapes(2)? The main thing I don't like about this method is it's general and I'm afraid that somewhere down the road it might not be Shape(2) anymore, causing issues. My hope is to define it by name, but I don't know what that is since it's created via an effect.

Is there by chance a function or something to look up an unknown shape name?

I found .findeshape, but I couldn't get it to work and I'm not sure if that's what I actually need in this instance. Any help is appreciated.

````
'Create Rectangle
    Set Rect = ActiveLayer.CreateRectangle(1, 1, 0, 0)

'Apply .1" Outside Contour.
    Set Contour1 = ActiveLayer.Shapes(1).CreateContour(cdrContourOutside, 0.1, 1, cdrDirectFountainFillBlend, CreateCMYKColor(75, 68, 65, 90), CreateCMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 100), CreateCMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 100), 0, 0, cdrContourSquareCap, cdrContourCornerMiteredOffsetBevel, 15#)
    ActiveDocument.CreateSelection Contour1.Contour.ContourGroup, ActiveLayer.Shapes(1)
    ActiveSelection.Separate
    ActiveLayer.Shapes(2).ObjectData("Name").Value = "Renamed 2"
End Sub```
````

Comment: Is the host app Corel DRAW? If so, there's a likely more appropriate [tag:coreldraw] tag.

Comment: Yes the host app is Corel DRAW.